# JSF f:event safe to pass parameters?

Tags: events, jsf

I'm new in JSF so my knowledge about some tags it is not so good. 
And I'd like to know how safe is to pass a parameter in this case:

```
<f:event listener="#{backBean.myMethod(**param**)}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

Because, as I'm going to pass this "param", the users can't acess this information (changing this value mean a security flaw, and this can not happen). So I'm asking this to know if using this event is it possible to break this code (passing another param)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

If the `param` value cannot be controlled by the enduser, then you're safe. Simple as that. Anything which you directly or indirectly (through JSF or from the DB!) extract from the `HttpServletRequest` falls under **full** control of the enduser.

So if you for example hardcode it,

```
<f:event listener="#{backBean.myMethod('foo')}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

then you're safe.

But if you pass an user-controlled request parameter,

```
<f:event listener="#{backBean.myMethod(param.foo)}" type="preRenderView"/>
```

then you're only safe if you **validate** its value in the server side.

Comment: thank you for the help. So in my case I'm going to pass the parameter as the first situation you posted. Just to understand a bit more, this whole tag, the user has no access to it, to any information (considering the case 'foo')? How is it possible? This code (f:event...) is accessed just in the server side?

Comment: It's executed entirely server side. I think that it helps more if you realize that the webbrowser doesn't retrieve JSF source code at all. It only retrieves its generated HTML output. Rightclick the JSF page in webbrowser and choose *View Source* to see it yourself. It would also help if you learn how HTTP, HTML and Servlets works by going through the basic HTTP, HTML and Servlet tutorials. The enduser has only control over anything which is retrieved with the HTTP response (JavaScript, for example!) and is been sent through the HTTP request (headers, parameters and the body).